# Need help understanding the wordpress function wp_oembed_add_provider( )

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm trying to add certain websites to Wordpress's video embed whitelist so that I can embed videos from those sites. I was told to use a function called wp_oembed_add_provider() with parameters $format, $provider, $regex in the functions.php file.

I've been trying to embed this video: https://video.dailymail.co.uk/preview/mol/2018/09/28/6032462726165936930/964x580_MP4_6032462726165936930.mp4

by putting the function at the bottom of functions.php with this format:

wp_oembed_add_provider( 'https://www.video.dailymail.co.uk/preview/*', 'https://www.video.dailymail.co.uk/oembedprovider' );

I've tried this and other variations but nothing seems to work. What I am doing wrong?

Also, is there a way to allow embedding from all websites instead of just one with this function? Thanks!

Comment: Have you referenced the [official documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_add_provider)? What specifically is unclear?

Comment: Like for example, I have a video link from the Daily Mail: https://video.dailymail.co.uk/preview/mol/2018/09/28/5030063773413429215/636x382_MP4_5030063773413429215.mp4 I'm not sure what part of this URL I need to put into the function in order to allow videos from the Daily Mail to be able to be embedded